# Clearly explain second harmonic generation?

Tags: optics, visible-light, non-linear-optics, harmonics

I'm having trouble learning about [Second Harmonic Generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-harmonic_generation).  I'd like to see those steps explained to me simply.

Answer (score 4):

Let's see if this explanation works for you. It is more intuitive than rigorous - but maybe it will help.

In a "normal" simple harmonic oscillator, the potential well is a parabola, and the restoring force is proportional to the displacement. We know that the equation of motion for such a well is a sinusoid.

Now if we make the potential well "more than parabolic" (for example, we add a 4th order term), then when the displacement gets larger, the restoring force will get larger more quickly than linearly:

$$V = a \cdot x^4\\
F = \frac{dV}{dx} = 4a \cdot x^3$$

As the object oscillating moves further from the center, it will experience a strong restoring force. This will "flatten" the top of the sinusoidal motion.

Now if you want to draw a "flattened" sinusoid, one way to do it is to add another component with three times the frequency:

[image]

This is backwards - but it is showing that a flattened sinus (as you would get from a non-parabolic potential well) can be represented as a sum of waves with different frequencies - the higher harmonics appear...

Note though that this is a third, not second, harmonic. The second harmonic requires an asymmetrical potential well - one that has a steeper slope in one direction than in the other.

I will leave it up to you to draw the same diagram (adding a small second order component) to convince yourself that indeed, in such a case you get a wave form that is flatter on one side, and more peaked on the other.

As I said - nothing rigorous, but maybe some food for thought.

Comment: Thank you, this is excellent! I'm going to try what you said. I get the principle, but the flattened part at the top shouldn't be so discrete as in your plot, right? Like, the fact that $F\sim x^3$ is different than $F\sim x$ should affect it during the whole path, right?

Comment: My plot got cut off a little bit - how flat it is obviously depends on the details of the shape of the potential well and the amplitude. I just wanted to show that the distortion of a sine wave can be approximated by a (series of) higher frequency components - think Fourier transform...

Comment: Floris, thanks so much. I'll redraw it and gain an intuitive understanding, and post back to my OP with it.